# jquery dynamically created element not triggering onchange

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I have been researching the .on() function within jquery to update the DOM of a dynamic form and trigger an event onchange of a newly created dropdown box.

I've linked a fiddle here:
http://jsfiddle.net/6y18mho8/10/

the jquery I believe is causing my problem is here:

```
$('#orderDetail').ready(function () {
    $("[id^=PN_]").on('change',function(event) {
        var PN = $(event.target).val();
        var ID = event.target.id;
        alert('Successfully triggered by onChange from "'+ID+'"');  
    });
});
```

The code will fire on the initial row but not on newly created.  Again, from everything I've read I need to reload/redefine the DOM to include my new elements via the .on() method.  Am I on the right track and if so what am I missing?

Any guidance on this would be much appreciated.

Comment: `$('parent_selector').on('change', 'event_selector', function(){});`

Comment: `$('#orderDetail').ready(function () {` is also wrong. As the dupe says: `$('#orderDetail').on('change',"[id^=PN_]", function(){ console.log(this.value); });`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like below!

```
$(".orderDetail").on('change', '[id^=PN_]', function(event) {
    var PN = $(event.target).val();
    var ID = event.target.id;
    alert('Successfully triggered by onChange from "'+ID+'"');
});
```

- If your jQuery version 1.7 then can use `delegate()`
- For 1.7+ use `.on` like this `$('parent_selector').on('event', 'event_selector', function(){});`